# PDF Storage System with REST API

Tags: rest, pdf, storage

I have hundreds of thousands of PDFs that are presently stored in the filesystem. I have a custom application that, as an afterthought to its actual purpose, provides access to these PDFs. I would like to take the "storage & retrieval" part out of the custom application and use an OpenSource document storage backend.

Access to the PDF Store should be via a REST API, so that users would not need a custom client for basic document browsing and viewing. Programs that store PDFs should also be able to work via the REST API. They would provide the actual binary or ASCII data plus structured meta data, which could later be used in retrieval.

A typical query for retrieval would be "give me all documents that were created between days X and Y with document types A or B".

My research, whether such a storage backend exists, has come up empty. Do any of you know a system that provides these features? OpenSource preferred, reasonably priced systems considered.

I am not looking for advice on how to "roll my own" using available technologies. Rather, I'm trying to find out whether that can be avoided. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe sounds like a document management or asset management system of which there are many; and many work with PDF files. I have some fleeting experience with commercial offerings such as Xinet (http://www.northplains.com/xinet - now acquired apparently) or Elvis (http://www.elvisdam.com). Both might fit your requirements but they're probably too big and likely too expensive.

Have you looked at Alfresco? This is an open source alternative I came into contact with years ago while being on the board of a selection committee. As far as I remember it definitely goes in the direction of what you are looking for and it is open source so might fit that angle as well: http://www.alfresco.com.

Comment: My thinking was that it might be overkill to use a full-blown Content Management System just for storing unstructured PDFs. However, upon your answer I checked out Alfresco and found that it provides not only a REST API, but that there is a standard for that called CMIS. What's more, Apache has a CMIS implementation called Chemistry, which appears to be a lot leaner than Alfresco. This looks like a promising road, thank you very much for your answer.